# Global Variables in Jenkins Shared libraries

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile which uses a shared library. I would like to make a global variable which is usable in all functions of the shared library, similar to the [`params`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) object. However I always end up with

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipelineParams for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Following [this guideline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables), I define a `Field` in the `Jenkinsfile`:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
@groovy.transform.Field
def pipelineParams

library identifier: 'pipeline-helper@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
       remote: 'https://bitbucket/scm/jenkins/pipeline-helper.git',
       credentialsId: 'bitbucket.service.user'
  ])

defaultCiPipelineMSBuild {
    nodes     = 'TEST-NODES' /* label of jenkins nodes*/
    email     = 'example@example.com' /* group mail for notifications */
    msbuild   = 'MSBUILD-DOTNET-4.6' /* ms build tool to use */ 
}
```

And then in the `defaultCiPipelineMSBuild` I set the `pipelineParams`

```
def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {
    ...
```

Later on I call a function `buildApplication` which want's to consume the variable:

```
def msBuildExe = tool pipelineParams.msbuild
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating a whole new pipeline parameter your self, did you try adding your variables into already available `env` parameter which you can use across your shared libraries?

```
env.param_name = "As per your requirement"
```

Can also be accessible with `env.param_name` or `env[param_name]` across shared library

Comment: That was a good hint, yes it is possible even so for non-strings. I will write a separate answer for thsi

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Dillip it is possible to use `env` even so for non-strings. If the object stored as environment variable is a list or a map, it shall be deserialized

So I slightly changed the pipeline code to store the map as environment variable

```
def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    env.pipelineParams = pipelineParams

    pipeline {
    ...
```

The pipeline is serialized and thus when reading returns a String

```
{ nodes=TEST-NODES,email=example@example.com,msbuild=MSBUILD-DOTNET-4.6 }
```

Thus for usage it has to be deserialized

```
def pipelineParams = 
// Take the String value between the { and } brackets.
"${env.pipelineParams}"[1..-2]
    .split(', ')
    .collectEntries { entry -> 
        def pair = entry.split('=')
        [(pair.first()): pair.last()]
    }

//use map
pipelineParams.msbuild
```

You may add the deserialization into a function so you can use it in other places as well.